# angularjs pass grandparent to grandson with components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

let me give an example if I could with 3 components:

```
<grandparent>
    <parent>
        <grandson>
```

If grandparent has an object, let us say a person

```
const person = {
    name: 'William',
    age: 102
}
```

How would the grandson be able to inherit that value from grandparent?

```
<title={{ $ctrl.person.name }}>
```

won't work because the `$ctrl` would be the parent.

hoping that my lighthearted example is taken as such.

Comment: Components use isolate scope. They do not inherit from ancestors. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

Comment: thank you. I do understand that this does happen. I am looking to find out how to pass down data to the grandson.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8CMPy4?p=preview)

Here is the updated code:

```
<grand-parent>
  <cbs-cus-comp com-bind='grandParentCntAs.name'>
    <child child-com-bind='cbsCusCompCntAs.name'></child>
  </cbs-cus-comp>
</grand-parent>
```

You need to provide something like below to make that happen:

```
  var cbsCusComp        =   {
                            transclude  :   true,
                            require: {grandParentComp:'^grandParent'},
                            template    :   'Parent : <b>{{cbsCusCompCntAs.comBind}}</b><br /><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
                            controller  :   cbsCusCompCnt,
                            controllerAs:   'cbsCusCompCntAs',
                            bindings    :   {comBind:'='}
                        };
```

Comment: Thank you. I did an edit on my question because I passed by mentioning that these are components.

Comment: @pertrai1 Any comments ?

Answer (score 0):

You have few options here:

1. Drill down the person object, pass it to the parent and the from the parent to the grandson
2. Use a service to store the person object and the in grandson use that service to get the person object
3. Use pattern like [redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: You forgot to mention the `require` property. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication).

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ### Intercomponent Communication
>
> Directives can `require` the controllers of other directives to enable communication between each other. This can be achieved in a component by providing an object mapping for the `require` property. The object keys specify the property names under which the required controllers (object values) will be bound to the requiring component's controller.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)